# Is the union of two projective curves in the projective plane a projective curve?

Tags: abstract-algebra, complex-analysis, algebraic-geometry, algebraic-curves, projective-geometry

As the title suggests, is the union of two projective curves in the projective plane a projective curve? Any help would be appreciated, thanks.

Comment: Yes, it's a projective curve. But at intersection points, there will be nilpotent elements in the local ring.

Comment: How do I prove this?

Comment: Not necessarily nilpotents, but zero divisors. As to how to prove it, you need to show that the union is $V(I)$ for some $I$. Is there a logical candidate?